# How can didEnter and didExit method work?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some issue .In my code monitoring location successful.But the problem is did enter and did exit method not woking.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications



class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    let ENTERED_REGION_MESSAGE = "Welcome to Playa Grande! If the waves are good, you can try surfing!"
    let ENTERED_REGION_NOTIFICATION_ID = "EnteredRegionNotification"
    let EXITED_REGION_MESSAGE = "Bye! Hope you had a great day at the beach!"
    let EXITED_REGION_NOTIFICATION_ID = "ExitedRegionNotification"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.mapView.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()



        self.locationManager.delegate = self

    }

    func setUpGeofenceForPlayaGrandeBeach() {

        let geofenceRegionCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.55756653, 88.41584444);
        let geofenceRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: geofenceRegionCenter, radius: 10, identifier: "boise" );





        geofenceRegion.notifyOnExit = true;
        geofenceRegion.notifyOnEntry = true;

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)
        let mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: geofenceRegionCenter, span: span)
        self.mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)

        let regionCircle = MKCircle(center: geofenceRegionCenter, radius: 400)
        self.mapView.addOverlay(regionCircle)
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true;

        self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion)
    }

    //MARK - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {
            //App Authorized, stablish geofence
            self.setUpGeofenceForPlayaGrandeBeach()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
        print("Started Monitoring Region: \(region.identifier)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {



       print("in: \(region.identifier)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Exit Region",EXITED_REGION_MESSAGE)
      print("out: \(region.identifier)")
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }



    //MARK - MKMapViewDelegate

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let overlayRenderer : MKCircleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay);
        overlayRenderer.lineWidth = 4.0
        overlayRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 7.0/255.0, green: 106.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        overlayRenderer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 203.0/255.0, blue: 208.0/255.0, alpha: 0.7)
        return overlayRenderer
    }
}
```

In this code started monitoring and geo fence created .but did enter and exit method not working.Please help me.

Comment: Could you set the delegate before you call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`? (Not saying that doing so will fix your problem but it kind of sticks out)

Comment: I do . But the problem is same . please help me .

Comment: Also can you confirm that the `mapView` shows the user entering the circle region? Additionally `startUpdatingLocation` may need to be called after you `startMonitoring`.

Comment: still not working. Can u please provide some code .

Comment: 10m is a small radius for a region. You should use at least 100m. How are you testing location entry? Are you physically entering the region or simulating location?  How long are you remaining inside the region.